# QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread не работает QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Создаю сервер на `Qt`, создаются два `socket` в отдельных потоках.

Так вот, прилетает та ошибка, при том что `socket` читает данные, но не записывает. Как раз на записи и вылетает эта долбанная ошибка.

Код из класса `MyRunnable` который наследует `QRunnable`.

Я использую `QThreadPool`.

```
void MyRunnable::run()
{
    m_pEventLoop = new QEventLoop();
    m_pSocket = new Socket();

    if(m_pSocket->setSocketDescriptor(m_socketDecriptor))
    {
        m_pSocket->write("200 Welcome\r\n");               connect(m_pSocket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(onConnected()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(m_pSocket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(onDisconnect()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(m_pSocket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onReadyRead()),Qt::QueuedConnection);            
    }

    m_pEventLoop->exec();    
}

void MyRunnable::setDescriptor(qintptr descriptor)
{
    m_socketDecriptor = descriptor;
}

void MyRunnable::onConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "Connected";
}

void MyRunnable::onDisconnect()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected";
    m_pSocket->close();
    m_pSocket->deleteLater();
    m_pEventLoop->exit();
    m_pEventLoop->deleteLater();    
}

void MyRunnable::onReadyRead()
{
    const QString& line = m_pSocket->readAll();

    qDebug() << line;
    parsecommand->parse(line);
    const QMap<QString,QString> & parametrs = parsecommand->map;
    const QString & command = parametrs.value("command");

    if(command == "live") {
      //  mapSocket->insert("dataSoc",m_pSocket);
          m_pSocket->write("live");
        live();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять способ коннекта с Qt::QueuedConnection на Qt::DirectConnection

Comment: Тут у меня подозрения на QEventEnable, который создает свой поток

Comment: Заработало, только вопрос, в чем фишка?

Comment: Фишка в том, что вы создаете Socket в одном потоке, а слоты, при коннекте типа Qt::QueuedConnection, выполнялись в другом. А когде мы поменяли на DirectionConnection слоты стали выполнятся в тоже потоке, в котором вы создали ваш сокет

Comment: тогда это ответ) Если знаете, подскажите еще с QEventLoop , это  просто пустой луп что бы не выйти из функции run?

Comment: Нет, не пустой. Это локальный цикл, локальных сообщений QEvent, как следует из его названия. В вашем случае да, это пустой локальный бесконечный цикл )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фишка в том, что вы создаете Socket в одном потоке, а слоты, при коннекте типа Qt::QueuedConnection, выполнялись в другом. А когда мы поменяли на DirectionConnection, слоты стали выполнятся в тоже потоке в котором вы создали ваш сокет.